# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a preexisting form  which I'm trying to add jquery validation to containing :

```
<form id="form" method="POST" action="/title/">
    {% csrf_token %}
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="6">
<input type="hidden" name="custom_checkbox_Electronic_Signature_man" value="1">
                            <p> <span class="style9">First Name </span>
                              <input type="text" name="first_name" value="" size="20" class="style7"><span class="style9">
                            Last Name </span>
                              <input type="text" name="last_name" value="" size="20" class="style7"><span class="style9">
```

Using the jquery validator plugin, I have added:

```
$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        first_name: {
            minlen: 3,
            maxlength: 15,
            required: true
        },
        last_name: {
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 15,
            required: true
        },
        email: {
          required: true,
          email: true
        },
         phone1: {
             required: true,
             phoneUS: true
          },
        phone2: {
             required: true,
             phoneUS: true
          },
            street: {
            required: true
          },
              city: {
            required: true
          },
              state: {
            required: true
          },
              zip: {
            zipcodeUS: true
          }

    },
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.style9').addClass('.style13');
        //$(element).addClass('.style13');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.style9').removeClass('.style13');
        //$(element).removeClass('.style13');
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'style13',
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if(element.parent('.input-group').length) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
});
```

I'm getting the error listed above . What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what does the error trace look like? also where is class .input-group in the html

Comment: I had the same problem only I had `minLength` instead of `minlength`. It's always the stupid stuff that kills me.

Comment: @yankeyhotel exactly that was my issue.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Replace `minlen` with `minlength`, and it works, there is no `minlen` property, so `call` fails internally

```
$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        first_name: {
            minlength: 3,  // <- here
            maxlength: 15,
            required: true
        },
        last_name: {
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 15,
            required: true
        },
   ..........
```

Answer (score 7):

Generally speaking this is an error that can be raised if you have set a non valid jQuery validation rule.
You can find the valid validation rules using [this](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/) link.

Comment: For my case, I made typo error: The first argument of method addMethod() should have been "postalcoderequiredif", not "requiredif"

$.validator.addMethod("requiredif", function (value, element, params) {
            ....
        });

        $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("postalcoderequiredif", ["dependentproperty", "targetproperty"], function (options) {
            ...
        });

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("noSpace", function(value, element){
            return value.indexOf("  ")<0 && value !==""; 
    }, "Space are not allowed");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                $('form').validate({
    rules: {
        first_name: {
            minlen: 3,
            maxlength: 15,
            required: true
        },
        last_name: {
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 15,
            required: true
        },
        email: {
          required: true,
          email: true
        },
         phone1: {
             required: true,
             phoneUS: true
          },
        phone2: {
             required: true,
             phoneUS: true
          },
            street: {
            required: true
          },
              city: {
            required: true
          },
              state: {
            required: true
          },
              zip: {
            zipcodeUS: true
          }

    },
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.style9').addClass('.style13');
        //$(element).addClass('.style13');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.style9').removeClass('.style13');
        //$(element).removeClass('.style13');
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'style13',
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if(element.parent('.input-group').length) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
});
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you did not include the jQuery validation script twice.
I had this done, I have included it in the Layout and the Create views, which makes the problem. I removed it from the create view.