# Jquery validation not being applied to field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

[image]

I have a preexisting form  which I'm trying to add jquery validation to containing :

```
         <p><span class="style9">City </span>
                        <input type="text" name="city" value="" size="20" class="style7"><span class="style9">
                        State </span>
                        <input type="text" name="state" value="" size="20" class="style7"><span class="style9">
                        Zip </span>
                        <input type="text" name="zip" value="" size="20" class="style7"><span class="style9">
                        Zip </span>
                        </p>
```

Using the jquery validator plugin, I have added:

```
$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        first_name: {
            minlen: 3,
            maxlength: 15,
            required: true
        },
        last_name: {
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 15,
            required: true
        },
        email: {
          required: true,
          email: true
        },
         phone1: {
             required: true,
             phoneUS: true
          },
        phone2: {
             required: true,
             phoneUS: true
          },
            street: {
            required: true
          },
              city: {
            required: true
          },
              state: {
            required: true
          },
              zip: {
            zipcodeUS: true
          }

    },
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.style9').addClass('.style13');
        //$(element).addClass('.style13');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.style9').removeClass('.style13');
        //$(element).removeClass('.style13');
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'style13',
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if(element.parent('.input-group').length) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see in the screenshot the first 2 fields get the validation applied, but not the last. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's simple, if you want an empty field to be "required", you must use the `required` rule on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the field "required" when it's left empty, you **must** use the `required` rule on it...

```
zip: {
   required: true,  // <- prevent it from being left empty
   zipcodeUS: true
}
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/rr8u9a46/**

---

---

As noted in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28410596/594235), you've also misspelled the `minlength` rule on your `first_name` field.

```
$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        first_name: {
            minlen: 3,  // <-- minlength
            maxlength: 15,
            required: true
        },
        .....
```

---

**NOTE**:  To use the `zipcodeUS` method, you **must** include [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/additional-methods.js), which contains this rule.

Comment: Aah! I should have seen that! Thank you very much. You got it working. - Bill